# Turn all entities to faults when app goes to background?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to turn all objects in my context to faults to save memory when my app goes to background. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want us to do the job for you? If no share your code, then we all be glad to help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can turn objects into faults with `refreshObject:mergeChanges:`.

For all the gory details, please see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html).

Comment: While correct, it is unnecessary on going to the background.  Trying to optimize Core Data's memory management usually causes you to get in the way.  Better to let Core Data manage that part.